# Online and offline tiles in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cartography

I have various problems in attempting to show tiles from two different sources in Leaflet :

- 1: The first view doesn't match the center I have defined, but if I move the window, the center of the map changes and it is centered correctly. I don't know why leaflet does this, as it works correctly with just one tile source
- 2: when I switch form one layer to the other, nothing happens
- 3: not all the data is loading, even for the online tile server.

My code:

```
var mapOnlineUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var mapOfflineUrl = 'data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var onlineTile = L.tileLayer(mapOnlineUrl, {attribution: mapAttribution});
var offlineTile = L.tileLayer(mapOfflineUrl, {attribution: mapAttribution});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [46.5, 2.9],
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 8,
    /* fixing tap http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-tap */
    tap: true,
    /* layers */
    layers: [onlineTile, offlineTile, myMarkerSet, MyOtherMarkerSet],
    /* attribution */
    attributionControl: false,
    /* zoom params */
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    boxZoom: false,
    /* keyboard */
    keyboard: false
});
L.control.attribution({position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
L.control.scale({position: 'bottomleft', imperial: false}).addTo(map);

// ADD GEOJSON'S LAYERS
// groups
var tiles = {
    "online data": onlineTile,
    "offline data": offlineTile
};
L.control.layers(tiles, markers, {collapsed: true, autoZIndex: false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: My two tiles servers seems superimposed, but i don't want that !

Comment: What are you expecting? It is normal for tiles to be on top of each other.

Comment: I want tiles loaded only if i choose it with the radio button. It's for an android app, i don't want that user load external ressource if he doesn't choose it. I want offline tiles (local) loaded by default, and distant server tile loaded only if user select it.